# Return a boolean from a closure

Tags: swift, closures

I have been searching in Swift documentation and googling but can't find how to return a value from a block like this:

```
func checkIfplayerFellDown() -> Bool {
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("brick", usingBlock: {
        (node: SKNode!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) -> Bool in
        if (node.position.y < self.player.position.y) { return false }
    })
    return true
}
```

The problem is because I do not understand blocks. I usually use them like this:

```
world.enumerateChildNodesWithName("name") {node, stop in
        if (node.position.y < self.size.height*0.5) {
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
```

How can I return a boolean from any of this closures? I know I should probably use a syntax out somewhere and I tried some things but none of them worked because I have no idea how the blocks even work.

Any explanation or an example of how this should be done is appreciated.

Comment: Her first code block won't work because the `return false` inside the block returns from the block, but doesn't make `enumerateChildNodesWithName` return at all, and doesn't make the `checkIfplayerFellDown` function return false either. In fact it causes a compile-time error because the block must return void, not a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a local variable (outside the block but inside the method) to pass the result out of the block, and also set `stop` to `true` when you want to stop the iteration:

```
func playerFellDown() -> Bool {
    var result = true
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("brick") { (child, stopOut) in
        if child.position.y < self.player.position.y {
            result = false
            stopOut.memory = true
        }
    }
    return result
}
```